# Delay in openURL(url) for phone calls

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl

I wrote a barebones app based on the Single View template that just makes a call when the application becomes active.  I found that there's a consistent 10 second delay when I execute openURL to make a phone call.

```
-(void) dial {
    NSLog(@"LOADED");
    NSString *number = @"1NNNNNNNNNN";  // Actual number here - hardcoded for testing
    NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", number]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        NSLog(@"Calling");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
        NSLog(@"Exiting");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not calling");
    }
}
```

It's called here:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"AppName: applicationDidBecomeActive");

    ViewController *vc = (ViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
    [vc dial];
}
```

Here's what I get with the logs:

```
2014-08-24 15:55:00.954 AppName[899:60b] applicationDidBecomeActive
2014-08-24 15:55:00.956 AppName[899:60b] LOADED
2014-08-24 15:55:00.979 AppName[899:60b] Calling
2014-08-24 15:55:10.988 AppName[899:60b] Exiting
2014-08-24 15:55:12.193 AppName[899:60b] applicationDidEnterBackground
2014-08-24 15:55:12.196 AppName[899:60b] applicationWillTerminate
```

I've tried building for Release, enabling all optimizations, and a bunch of others, but none of them seemed to have helped.

I've seen 3rd party apps that trigger phone calls and don't have this 10-second delay (I've seen others that have them, too). Does anyone how I can avoid this delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be iOS7 specific.  iOS 6 apps didn't have this problem, and iOS 8 no longer has this problem.

Comment: I am highly skeptical that this is actually a bug, I've implemented quite a few iOS 7 apps that use this feature and none have any delay. Unfortunately, all my devices are now running iOS 8 so I can't verify.